# Why is ?XDEBUG_PROFILE=true being ignored by mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, profiling, xdebug

I have installed xdebug into my PHP and would like to execute the profiler using ?XDEBUG_PROFILE=true in the url string. However, when I try to do this with a url which has a mod_rewrite RewriteRule with a query string, it doesn't profile. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/last$       page.php?pageid=$1 [L]
```

What is the best way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `[QSA]` flag to append any query string onto the rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/last$       page.php?pageid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To only allow `XDEBUG_PROFILE`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^XDEBUG_PROFILE
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/last$       page.php?pageid=$1&XDEBUG_PROFILE=1 [L]

# Other requests go through as normal
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/last$       page.php?pageid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really like the sound of it. Doesn't that mean that then anyone could pass any query string to my script? Thus opening up the GET variables to hackers.

Comment: @David Then try what I just added. Any query param is not allowed, but `XDEBUG_PROFILE` is.  In any case, you can just remove the `QSA` when you are done profiling since you should disable xdebug in production anyway.

Comment: @david: nothing stops someone from typing  `example.com/yourscript?hahah=im_in_url_url&adding=stuffz` into their address bar.